# sql server bulk insert text field wrong format

Tags: sql-server-2005, bulkinsert, file-format

I have used a format file to do a bulk insert and found that the field I have imported appears as chinese instead of english text. Unusual since the import file saved as UTF-8 contains english characters.

```
8.0
1
1       SQLNCHAR  0   100    ""   3   QueryTerms    SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

text as it appears now

```
믯溿睥洠摥慩猠牴瑡来
```

text as it supposed to appear

```
new media
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the Chinese characters and all it came down in the end was changing SQLNCHAR to SQLCHAR in the format file...

```
9.0
4
1 SQLCHAR 0 10  ","    1 Field1 SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
2 SQLCHAR 0 10  ","    2 Field2 SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3 SQLCHAR 0 6   ","    3 Field3 SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
4 SQLCHAR 0 100 "\r\n" 4 Field4 SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```